# Adding data from plist from array

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray, plist

So I am new to programming and have been stuck on this for days...
I have an array as shown here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com    /DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 2 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>7</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 3 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>6</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I then want to store these an array for each. I then have a label in my story board for each and want to assign each key to a different label but I seem to be doing that wrong. Here is my code

```
- (void)showNextQuestion
{
    NSArray *rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    currentQuestion = -1;
    currentQuestion++;

    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];

    for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
        [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
        [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
        [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
        [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];

        self.questionasked.text =question;
        self.answer1.text = A;
        self.answer2.text = B;
        self.answer3.text = C;
    }
}
```

The 4 labels are questionsasked, answer1, answer2, answer3...how do I assign it properly

Comment: you appear to be assigning an NSMutableArray to the text field of a label. Since you have multiple questions, you will need to specific the index of the question you want to display in the `self.?????.text = ?;` line

Comment: Hey david. Thanks for your help what i want to do is take what ever is in the array, say question and put it in the questionasked label...does that make sense?

Comment: understood, but you only have 1 set of labels and multiple questions, and you are assigning to the labels in the for statement, so you are overwriting the assignments too. Do you mean to put the question in a Table view or something, then display the possible answers in buttons with a question is selected? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: OKAY..i understand what you mean..So I will have to create a loop for the number of items in the array. Maybe i have bitten off more than I can chew here. So for arguments sake say there is only one item in the array in the plist how would i assign the key to a specific label that i created from the plist to the label ...?does that make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum, you should remove the assignments from the for loop and rewrite as:

```
    self.questionasked.text =question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
```

I would also suggest that you only load the file once (rather than on every showNextQuestion call)

Also, your setting of `currentQuestion=-1` will only ever show you the first question, no matter how many times you call it. Move this statement to the Constructor or somewhere where it will only be executed once.

Comment: what method should i put it in david, sorry as I said i am new to all of this...pretty unsure

Comment: either your constructor, or your viewDidLoad

Comment: okay david I have done that... I think im half way through getting the problem solved, could I send you on some of my revised code as I am limited to space here

Comment: I'm about done for the day, but if you want to post your code, I can take a look at it later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Okay david thanks very much for your help really appreciata it...I will post a link here